# WinForms DataGridView Data Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, .net-4.7.2

```
// Object Model
public class LineItem
{
  public PropA { get; set; }

  public PropB { get; set; }
}

public class CustomLineItem : LineItem
{
  public PropC { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSelection : Collection<LineItem> 
{
}

// UI Layer
ItemSelection items = Service.GetItemsFromDatabase(); // Contains objects of type CustomLineItem

BindingSource bsLineItems = new BindingSource();
bsLineItems.DataSource = items;

this.dgvLineItems.AutoGenerateColumns = false; // Columns added via designer and DataPropertyName attribute has been set for all columns
this.dgvLineItems.DataSource = this.bsLineItems;
```

**Issue:**
The DataGridView binds with properties `PropA` and `PropB`, but not `PropC` because of the inheritance. Please note that this is an existing solution and I am unable to modify the definition of the `ItemSelection` class. Otherwise I would convert this class to a generic implementation, like `ItemSelection<T> where T : LineItem`.

Any other way out?

Comment: If you can show your columns definitions from designer file that would be helpful? Also is the propC available in the items collection?

Comment: Yes, PropC exists in the items collection.

`this.dgcPropA = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.dgcPropA.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.dgcPropA.HeaderText = "Prop A";
this.dgcPropA.Name = "dgcPropA";
this.dgcPropA.ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: You don't have `DataPropertyName` that specifies which property the column will bind to?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. DataPropertyName is being set. I have stated it in my question as well.

Comment: The issue is with inheritance, I believe.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, as far as the system knows, the objects are of type LineItem and not CustomLineItem. This means you can't access properties, methods, etc. of CustomLineItem object without casting back to CustomLineItem. Could you create class ItemSelection<T> : ItemSelection, Collection<T> where T : LineItem to expand on ItemSelection implementation? This would leave legacy stuff with the original definition while giving new stuff (like this) the expanded capabilities.

Comment: @Adam - I understand where you are going. But, cannot extend both `ItemSelection` and `Collection<T>`, both being classes.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write ICollection<T>. class ItemSelection<T> : ItemSelection, ICollection<T> where T : LineItem. ItemSelection already gives you Collection<LineItem> implementation. You just need to expand ICollection<T> (and whatever else is needed from ItemSelection) properties/methods to recast LineItem objects back to type T, as appropriate.